# how can get marker icon from the internet in flutter google map

Tags: dart, flutter, google-maps-markers

I have some icon on the internet, and I want to set those icons for flutter google marker, how can I do that?

One way is that get the image from the internet and convert it  to byte data and Uint8List finally set it on the marker with  BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes

I do that but not work

someone can help?

Comment: Add your code first and secondly what does this mean you want to get icons from internet?

Comment: Be specific of what you are asking

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use 'BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes' to display icons. According to the example below

```
      var iconurl ='your url';
      var dataBytes;
      var request = await http.get(iconurl);
      var bytes = request.bodyBytes;

      setState(() {
        dataBytes = bytes;
      });

      final Marker marker = Marker(
        markerId: markerId,
        icon: BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(dataBytes.buffer.asUint8List()),
        position: LatLng(
          lat,
          lng,
        ),
        infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: address, snippet: desc),
      );
```

Comment: Where best place to call the async functions?